Different versions of Python rand bash running and Visual Studio Code
I'm using Linux Mint version 21.3.  I installed Python3/pip3 (system package) in Software Manager. I installed Visual Studio code in Software manager as well (Flatpack). When I open a terminal directly from the desktop, I see:
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug  8 08:28 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.10*

and no entry for "python"
My bash version:
bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release

But in my Visual Studio Code, my bash version:
GNU bash, version 5.2.37(1)-release 

and Python:
lrwxrwxrwx 1 nfsnobody nfsnobody    16 Nov 21 14:23 /usr/bin/python -> /usr/bin/python3*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 nfsnobody nfsnobody    10 Nov 21 14:23 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.12*

So there's a different version of Python and bash (and an entry for "python"). I'm also not sure why it has "nfsnobody" as the owner.
VSC terminal settings:
{
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
        "bash": {
            "path": "bash",
            "icon": "terminal-bash"
        },
        "zsh": {
            "path": "zsh"
        },
        "fish": {
            "path": "fish"
        },
        "tmux": {
            "path": "tmux",
            "icon": "terminal-tmux"
        },
        "pwsh": {
            "path": "pwsh",
            "icon": "terminal-powershell"
        }
    },
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux": "bash",
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx": ""
}

Linux Mint:
RELEASE=21.3
CODENAME=virginia
EDITION="Xfce"
DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 21.3 Virginia"
DESKTOP=Gnome
TOOLKIT=GTK
NEW_FEATURES_URL=https://www.linuxmint.com/rel_virginia_whatsnew.php
RELEASE_NOTES_URL=https://www.linuxmint.com/rel_virginia.php
USER_GUIDE_URL=https://www.linuxmint.com/documentation.php
GRUB_TITLE=Linux Mint 21.3 Xfce


Are you running Visual Studio remotely to another server?  Is this native Linux, or are you running WSL on Windows?

@TimRoberts, no. This is native Linux Mint on a dual boot Windows/Linux system.

@TimRoberts, also, I'm running VSC locally.

There seem to be several issues with the settings.
To modify the root_squash option in an NFS (Network File System) server,
you can update the configuration.
DIR : /etc/exports
root_squash = default
-> no_root_squash

Would you like to set the VSC terminal settings as follows?
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux": "bash"
"terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "/usr/bin/bash"
"python.pythonPath": "/usr/bin/python3"


Corn, so wait, it's just root_squash = default that goes in the /etc/exports file, or all the text you wrote? BTW, I have a dual boot Windows/Linux Mint system, not a virtual machine or WSL.

In /etc/exports you will see an option set to roo_squash = default. Changing it to no_root_squash will fix nfsnobody. The terminal commands(Bash,Python) below are for modifying vsc terminal settings.
